# Is there a way to get the percentage for each level of a categorical variable in an entityset?

Tags: featuretools

Right now, for a categorical variable with levels A, B, and C, I can only get the mode for each user id. I'd also like to get the percentage of values for each level for each user id.

For example, using encode_features, I get that user1 has the following:

- MODE(variableX = A) = 0
- MODE(variableX = B) = 1
- MODE(variableX = C) = 0

But what I also want is:

- PERCENT(variableX = A) = .05
- PERCENT(variableX = B) = .5
- PERCENT(variableX = C) = .45

Is there a way to do this using Featuretools, or should I just recode each level as a boolean in the preprocessing stage? Thanks!

Comment: something like this is possible with a custom primitive. I can try to put an example up. In the meantime, I recommend the approach you suggests as recoding each level as a a boolean in preprocess. Then the mean primitive will calculate what you want.

Comment: @MaxKanter an example would be great, and I'll go ahead and recode the variable for now. Thanks for the feedback!